# Can I do an Unformatted Write to a File Then a Formatted Read From a File for Integral Types?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, ifstream, ofstream, formatted

Given that I write an `vector` of integers to temporary file unformatted:

```
ofstream foo("foo.txt", ios::binary);
const auto length= size(output);

foo.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(length), sizeof(length));

if(!empty(input)) foo.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data(output)), sizeof(decltype(output)::value_type) * length);
```

Can I do the following formatted read later from the file where `input` is the same type as `output`:

```
ifstream foo("foo.txt", ios::binary);
size_t size;

foo.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(size), sizeof(size));
input.resize(size);

if(!empty(input)) copy(istream_iterator<decltype(output)::value_type>(foo), istream_iterator<decltype(output)::value_type>(), begin(input));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do an Unformatted Write to a File Then a Formatted Read From a File for Integral Types?

No, you can't do that.

The contents of a file to which data are written using unformatted write will be very different from formatted write. An formatted read cannot accurately interpret the unformatted data.

Comment: What about `char`? I see only a problem of doing a formatted write and unformatted read there.

Comment: @LogicStuff, `char` will be OK as long as you don't skip whitespace when performing the formatted reads.

Comment: @LogicStuff You're right about `char`, but I just had a Brain Fart on this whole embarrassing question.